# HttpURLConnection modified to Apache HttpComponents

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm modifying my code to use Apache HttpComponents after I was advised it's a cleaner approach

HttpURLConnection code (working):

```
String names = "names[]=EndUser/WebTransaction/WebTransaction/JSP/index.jsp";

try (PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter()) {

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            conn.setRequestProperty("X-Api-Key", "myId");
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);

            OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.write(names);
            wr.flush();

            String line;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                writer.println(HTML_START + "<h2> NewRelic JSON Response:</h2><h3>" + line + "</h3>" + HTML_END);
            }
            wr.close();
            reader.close();
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is my code modified to use Apache HttpComponents(404 not found response):

```
try (PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter()) {
            HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("X-Api-Key", "myID"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("names[]", "EndUser/WebTransaction/WebTransaction/JSP/index.jsp"));
            HttpGet request1 = new HttpGet(url + URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs, "utf-8"));
            request1.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");


            HttpResponse response1 = client.execute(request1);
            System.out.println(response1.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());


            String line;
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response1.getEntity().getContent()));
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                writer.println(HTML_START + "<h2> NewRelic JSON Response:</h2><h3>" + line + "</h3>" + HTML_END);
            }

            reader.close();
        }catch(MalformedURLException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Could someone point out to me the correct way to accomplish this please.

Comment: When asking a question, include all necessary information. "Not working" is not at all helpful for anyone involved.

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting a not found 404 response

Comment: You can use wireshark or similar tool to compare whether the requests being sent are different.

Comment: That's a good idea, I would never have thought to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much much cleaner approach is to use Retrofit like library, Because these are boilerplate codes.

You can still use this code as a generic method to bring in Json objects so that you can process them and get what ever necessary information you want out of it.But it is not cleaner, It is messy trust me. :)

Since I do not have your actual API url I will try to give an example using [this API function](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/rest-api-v2/application-examples-v2/listing-your-app-id-metric-data-v2).

Retrofit is type safe, which means you specify the model pojo and it will take care of doing necessary casting to the Json object to your model itself which is cool.

model,

```
public class Application {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String language;
    private String health_status;

    //Getters and setters

}
```

dto,

```
public class ApplicationListDot {

   private List<Application> applications;

}
```

Interface,

```
public interface RestController {

    @GET("/v2/applications.json")
    ApplicationListDot viewApplications();

}
```

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment.

Comment: I can make this an answer

Comment: Then do so. Suggesting another library is not an answer.

Comment: Please if you could give me a example of the Retrofit code that would accomplish this and explain why it's a better approach?

Comment: @Johntk are you trying do a post in your second code snippet?

Comment: The response is a JSON object if that's what you're asking?

Comment: Ok cool, So, Is it s list of some objects or some random json object?eg, List of Person objects, Person object ?

Comment: Its pulling information using the "New Relic REST API"

Comment: @Johntk Do you need any more help on this?